# How to reduce mutability with nested objects stored in Realm?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, realm

[Full code on github](https://github.com/briancl2/WorkoutTracker/tree/master/Workout%20Tracker)

I am trying to rewrite my app to reduce mutability and take advantage of functional programming.  I am having trouble figuring out where to start, since it seems like my architecture is to use modification in place almost everywhere.  I could use some advice on a simple starting point of how to break this down into smaller pieces where I am maintaining immutability at each modification.  Should I change my data storage architecture so that I am only storing/modifying/deleting the leaf objects?

Right now, from the root ViewController, I load my one monster object `ExerciseProgram` (which contains a `RealmList` of `Exercise` objects, which contains a `RealmList` of `Workouts`, which contains a `RealmList` of `Sets`....)

```
final class ExerciseProgram: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var startDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var userProfile: User?
    var program = List<Exercise>()
    var count: Int {
        return program.count
    }
}
```

Loaded here one time in MasterTableViewController.swift:

```
func load() -> ExerciseProgram? {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(ExerciseProgram).first
}
```

and then modify the single `ExerciseProgram` object in place throughout the app, such as when recording a new workout.

To create a new `Workout`, I instantiate a new `Workout` object in RecordWorkoutTableViewController.swift:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if doneButton === sender {
        if let date = newDate, weight = newWeight, setOne = newSetOne, setTwo = newSetTwo {
            let newSets = List<WorkSet>()
            newSets.append(WorkSet(weight: weight, repCount: setOne))
            newSets.append(WorkSet(weight: weight, repCount: setTwo))
            newWorkout = Workout(date: date, sets: newSets)
        }
    }
}
```

Which unwinds to ExerciseDetailTableViewController.swift where the storage occurs into the same monster `ExerciseProgram` object retrieved at the beginning:

```
@IBAction func unwindToExerciseDetail(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? RecordWorkoutTableViewController, newWorkout = sourceViewController.newWorkout {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            exercise.recordWorkout(newWorkout)
        }
    }
}
```

This behavior is replicated all over my app.  If I want to edit or delete an existing workout, it's exactly the same.

The `Exercise` class is just this:

```
final class Exercise: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var notes: String?
    var workoutDiary = List<Workout>()
    dynamic var goal = 0

    ...

    func recordWorkout(newWorkout: Workout) {
        workoutDiary.append(newWorkout)
    }

    func replaceWorkout(originalWorkout: Workout, newWorkout: Workout) {
        workoutDiary[workoutDiary.indexOf(originalWorkout)!] = newWorkout
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are doing, however, you may want to look into using Primary keys from realm - if you want to break your objects up.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, looking at that schema, no, you shouldn't change it. If it's representing the types of information and their relations properly and it's already working in your app, then there's no need to change it.

If you feel it is overly complex or confusing, then it may be necessary to go back and look at your data model design itself before actually doing more work on the code itself. Review each relationship and each property in the linked objects, and make sure that it's absolutely critical that the data is saved at that level. In any case, Realm itself is very good at handling relationships between objects, so it's not 'wrong' to have several layers of nested objects.

Either way, Realm itself lends itself pretty well to functional programming since every property is explicitly immutable out of the box. Functional programming doesn't mean everything has to be immutable always though. Inevitably, you'll have to reach a point where you'll need to save changes to Realm; the mindset behind it is that you're not transforming data as you're working on it, and you minimise the number of points that actually do so.